# Random 502 errors on Laravel 9 Application

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch, redis, cloudflare

We have a Laravel 9 application, with some pages random returning 502 and 520 errors. We use cloudflare.

None of these 502 errors get logged in the error logs. Refreshing a page which errors will (99%) of the time then work.

Our stack is:
PHP 8.1
MySQL (Percona) 8
Redis 7.2
ElasticSearch 7.15

It doesn't appear to be a timeout issue, as they get logged.

Have used screamingfrog, and get around a 0.01% 5XX error rate.

Comment: It sounds sad..

Comment: Check your server settings.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.